# Remove npm packages both from dependencies and devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

With

```
npm uninstall --save package
```

we can remove `package` from the project. But if it is under `devDependencies`, it will be ignored. Is it possible to remove package from both kind of dependencies ?

I've also tried to combine those `save` flags:

```
npm uninstall --save --save-dev package
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**

You should be able to run

`npm uninstall -SD package`

to uninstall both types of dependencies.

From the docs:

> This uninstalls a package, completely removing everything npm installed on its behalf.

[See the docs here for more information.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall)

Comment: But that does not update the `package.json` file. Uninstalling with one of the `--save` options does.